# Apache Test page shown instead of ISPCofig

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, vmware-workstation

I'm new to ISPConfig and I used website tutorial to setup.
I have installed ISPConfig 3 on a vmware VM with CentOS 6.3. I use static IP for guest OS.
After installing ISPConfig 3, I went to host OS and tried to open ISPConfig webpage in browser. I used https://[guest-ip]:8080, but test page for apache was shown instead of ISPConfig 3 main page.
How can I fix this or how can I reach ISPConfig 3 control panel?

Comment: try to stop apache service and re run ISPConfig service to figure out.
sudo service apache2 stop

Comment: How to run ISPConfig Service?

Comment: /etc/rc.d/init.d/ispconfig_server start|stop|restart

Comment: There is no such a file there

Comment: There is a server.sh file in `/usr/local/ispconfig/server`. But when I run, it begins and finished immediately.

Comment: verify your installation and try to connect to change the port:


`cd /tmp`


`wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ispconfig/ISPConfig-3.0.4.2.tar.gz`


`tar zxvf ISPConfig-3.0.4.2.tar.gz`

`cd ispconfig3_install/install/`

`php -q install.php `

Comment: I just did it and there is no such a file in /etc/rc.d/init.d/

Comment: Hi Jalal did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm seeing exactly the same thing (including no `/etc/rc.d/init.d/ispconfig_server ` file and a `/usr/local/ispconfig/server/server.sh` that finishes immediately.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the test page:

Remove `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` (or rename it to something that does not end in .conf)

and / or

Stick an `index.html` page in `/var/www/html`.

The DocumentRoot (/var/www/html) in CentOS has nothing in it. The welcome.conf disables Apache's automatic indexes and sets a custom error page for http response 403 (Forbidden).  Since the autoindex is disabled, you get a 403.

Files ending in `.conf` that are located in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` are loaded in with the main configuration file which is located at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

```
[root@moon ~]# grep -i ^Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

So, main configuration in /etc/httpd/conf/.  Small configuration snippets (which are typically installed with packages that rely on the webserver) go in /etc/httpd/conf.d/.  The error pages are located in /var/www/error if you'd like to take a look.

I have no advice for ISPConfig; never used it.  CLI or die!

Comment: Thank you. The most important aspect of my problem is that you never used it! However thank you for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem. This is what fixed it for me (from [this thread](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1277717)):

```
yum install mod_fcgid
```

Then restart Apache with `/sbin/service/httpd restart`

---

This is odd because I had actually already installed `mod_fcgid` twice already, but reading around, it sounds like that install sometimes fails silently. If the above doesn't work, here's the things I installed between my first attempt (which didn't work) and my last (which did)

1. `yum install mod_fcgid httpd-itk` [first attempt, didn't work]
2. `yum install php php-devel php-gd php-imap php-ldap php-mysql php-odbc php-pear php-xml php-xmlrpc php-pecl-apc php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mssql php-snmp php-soap php-tidy curl curl-devel perl-libwww-perl ImageMagick libxml2 libxml2-devel mod_fcgid php-cli httpd-devel` [most of these were already installed - brute force to make sure nothing is missing]
3. `rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm` then `yum install fail2ban` after seeing the `server.sh` was complaining than fail2ban wasn't yet installed
4. `yum install mod_fcgid`

It's odd that it only worked on the third attempt (maybe it was adding the repository that did it?)